# Where to save files for Outlook Addin project

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I have written an AddIn for Microsoft Office Outlook which uploads email to a sharepoint server. I want to save a text log of what has been uploaded. Where is the best place to save this data?

```
'My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData
```

points to

```
'C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft Corporation\Microsoft Office Outlook\12.0.6550.5003
```

Would that be an ideal place to store such a log?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't log the username then yes, if you log the username then you can also save it in the ApplicationData folder.